# Parcel bundle different files

Tags: javascript, bundler, parcel

I have problem after bundling files with Parcel. Changes does not effect on page in browser, but the local files bundled are up-to-date. I checked it in "Source" files in ChromeDev and local files in "dist" folder (please find in screenshot). I have tried to look for in Parcel web page, but did not find anything.
Please find repository: https://github.com/Murad-Git/Spoon-Fork

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7RlG.png)

[VS code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l49h.png)

thanks for help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Installed:
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
"@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-nightly.2268",
"@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0-nightly.646",
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"parcel": "^2.0.0-nightly.644",

I do not know how, but it works now.